# Check dynamic checkboxes vbscript

Tags: excel, checkbox, vbscript, hta

I have a question about the use of checkboxes in VBscript. I have a large excel file with a few columns with data in it. I build my HTML using vbscript and read the checkbox name out of the excel file and I this it in an array. Until there, everything works.
When I want to check if the checkbox is checked, I get the error 'Object required' 'groupnames'
Of course I know what I dit wrong, but I can't seem to find a solution. Is there anyone who could help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Check groups</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Check groups"
  ID="Dynamically_check_groups"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, counter
dim groupnames(90)
counter = 0

Sub Window_OnLoad
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("D:\Groups.xls")
    dim strHTML, intRow
    For intRow = 2 to 90
        If objExcel.Cells(intRow,4).Value = "sport" Then
            if ObjExcel.Cells(intRow,5).Value = "vast" Then
                strHTML = strHTML & "<input type="&Chr(34)& "checkbox"&Chr(34)& "  name="&Chr(34)& objExcel.Cells(intRow,2) &Chr(34)& ">" &objExcel.Cells(intRow,1) &" <br>"
                groupnames(counter) = objExcel.Cells(intRow,2).value
                counter = counter + 1
            End if
        End if
    Next
    objExcel.Quit
    DataArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
End Sub

Sub Check_Groups
    Dim i, name
    For i = 0 to counter - 1  
        If groupnames(i).checked Then
            Msgbox groupnames(i) & "was checked."
        End if
    Next

End Sub
</SCRIPT>



<body bgcolor="white">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><Div id="DataArea"></Div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        <button style="width:200;height:50" name="chkgroups" id="chkgroups" accessKey="C" onClick="vbs:Check_groups">Controleer groepen</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
If groupnames(i).checked Then
```

tries to access the .checked property of a name/string that is the ith element in the array of strings named groupnames. What you need is the DOM object/element with that name. So

```
Set o = document.getElementById(groupnames(i))
If o.checked Then
```

Alternatively, you can access the .all collection:

```
Set o = document.all(groupnames(i))
```